# C++ not playing mp3 files through mciSendString

Tags: c++, audio, mp3, winmm, mci

I am aiming to build an audio player that plays MP3 files. For that, I have used the `mciSendString()` function. All the MP3 files are in the same folder as the main source file. I have looked at the documentation and some syntax online, despite that I am unable to play the MP3 files. When I select a song, it doesn't play, and the code skips to `system("pause")`.

My header files

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Winmm.lib")

using namespace std;
```

Function that plays the MP3 files:

```
void playsong()
{
    int song;
    system("cls");
    cout << "****************************" << endl;
    cout << "\tPLAYING SONG\n";
    cout << "****************************" << endl;
    cout << "List of Songs\n";
    cout << "1.0\n";
    cout << "2.AFSANAY\n";
    cout << "3.Agency\n";
       
    cin >> song;
    switch(song)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            mciSendString("open \"C:\\Users\Murad\Documents\3rd Semester\OOP\Assignments\Assignmnet 1\Assignmnet 1\0.mp3\" type mpegvideo alias mp3", NULL, 0, NULL);
            mciSendString("play mp3", NULL, 0, NULL); 
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
           mciSendString("open \"C:\\Users\Murad\Documents\3rd Semester\OOP\Assignments\Assignmnet 1\Assignmnet 1\AFSANAY.mp3\" type mpegvideo alias mp3", NULL, 0, NULL);
           mciSendString("play mp3", NULL, 0, NULL);
           break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            mciSendString("open \"C:\\Users\Murad\Documents\3rd Semester\OOP\Assignments\Assignmnet 1\Assignmnet 1\Agency.mp3\" type mpegvideo alias mp3", NULL, 0, NULL);
            mciSendString("play mp3", NULL, 0, NULL);
            break;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    display();
}
```

Comment: One of the problems is the string that you have sent to `mciSendString`. Look up character escape sequences on Google

Answer (score 0):

Your `open` commands are not escaped correctly, and you are not checking return values for errors.

But even if no errors were occurring, the [`play`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/play) command is **asynchronous**, so `mciSendString()` will still exit immediately once playback begins. You need to specify the `wait` flag to wait for playback to finish, or else use the `notify` flag to be notified when playback is finished. See [The Wait, Notify, and Test Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/the-wait-notify-and-test-flags)